# SP2010 possible to create a text file in document library and fill with data from list using JSOM JavaScript/jquery

Tags: document-library, javascript, jquery, document

Is it possible to create a new item in a library and default that to a txt file or XML and using JavaScript or jquery insert data from a list into that file?

For example from a page click a button that fires JavaScript and creates new item in library...that item is based on blank text file, query a list for values and write them in the document?

Comment: Yes this is possible and it is a lot more code than I could demonstrate for all versions. Therefore which version of SharePoint are you using? Please state 2010/2013/365.

Comment: using SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 1):

This gives a few examples of using JS to create, update and delete SharePoint list items.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185011(v=office.14).aspx

It's working with lists, but I would imagine working with document libraries would be similar.